# Azure native way to get notified of resource addition/modification

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Actually I am working on an event based notification which will call a webhook/send an email in case a new resource gets added to my subscription. I could not find any Azure native service which will send me alerts/notification in case a new resource gets added to my subscription, but using powershell we can keep on polling on the resource list and workaround it, but if there is any native Azure service or function which can help me out, please inform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the azure [activity log alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-activity-log-alerts) to create a web hook/sms/email notification.  This allows you to create a direct avenue straight from the Azure tooling.  You can also use a [variety of other methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview) to monitor your azure subscription including [Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/) (event based logging, alerting and analytics) and [App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/) (application logging and alerting)

Comment: Yeah after posting this question I created oms and added log analytics to it. Took some time for logs to reflect but yeah was working like a charm. Thanks.